# Which US banks offer deposit-only, free ATM cards?

Tags: banking

I am a landlord and some of my tenants are "unbanked" i.e. they do not have bank accounts. My bank used to offer deposit-only ATM cards but not anymore. Does anyone know of any banks that offer these in 2019?

Minimum requirements:

1. Branch and ATM locations throughout USA.
2. Physical cards (like debit cards but deposit-only).
3. No limit on the amount of cash deposited.
4. Free as in actually free. For example it looks like Bank Of America offers "free" deposit-only cards but they charge an account fee, a cash handling fee, and a cash deposit processing fee (almost reads like a joke, doesn't it...) all adding up to $50-$150 per rent payment.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Product/service recommendation questions are off-topic. Sorry.

Comment: Googling "deposit-only ATM card" returned some interesting results.  Are there forums dedicate to landlords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a 501(c) club I know, they are ordering normal Debit Cards for their 'small business account', and set the withdrawal and purchase limits online to 0.00. That has worked fine for years, and is free because the average money in the account is above 3000 (although the users are typically not trying to game the system).

Comment: Setting the withdrawal and purchase limits to zero is a really clever hack! I will check with my bank to see if this is possible and post an update.

Comment: +1, though @RADA should check whether card holders are allowed to do account enquiries.